# Firebase Kotlin Auth Persist Login Throughout App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am a beginner to android programming, learning on my own. I am using `android studio 4.1.1' and` kotlin`.

I followed a tutorial to create a Firebase login setup.

```
... in part...

private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
...
// in override fun onCreate()
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

// once a user is logged in, I can do:
val userID = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid
```

The tutorial (and other tutorials and threads) did not cover whether the `mAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid` persists across multiple Activities or Fragments.  Is this possible?  How do I check for the `currentUser` on any given `.kt` file?

I could create a Global class with a `companion object{}` and set `Global.userID = "test"` then once I a user is logged in, I could set `Global.userID = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid`, but that doesn't seem like the best option.

Thanks for any advice or pointers.

Comment: Personally I don’t find it too troubling to test whether Auth.auth().currentUser is null or not. No apparent need to go global.

Comment: But on the other hand - if you’re thinking about gathering together some frequently used user methods - fun userIsLoggedIn() : Boolean { return Auth.auth().currentUser != null} could perhaps be something

Comment: You should use an AuthStateListener, to check the state of the user. This can be made no matter it's a fragment or an activity. Please check the duplicate.

Comment: @DanAbnormal  How do I get `Auth.auth().currentUser` to work in my second fragment?  It shows in red with not solutions that I understand.  Is there some package I need to import?  It does not prompt me for any.

Comment: @JohnCowan I'm sorry, I used iOS code. I meant to write that you can check if FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser is not null. You can do this anywhere in your app

Comment: @DanAbnormal  Thanks and no worries.  Scary to say, I'm enjoying learning this stuff.   "I THINK" I did try that one: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser`.  But, I tried a lot of things.  I will try it for sure now.

Comment: As far as I understand it should work; if currentUser != null a user is logged in

Comment: @DanAbnormal  Thank you for all your help.  This is working now.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good luck!